# Php page Load time varies a lot

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page that does calculations based on user input and a database to produce a report. 
The load time for this report varies dramatically for a reason I can not identify. I will load the page and it will take 25 to 30 sec. Then a few minutes later I will load the same report (with the same inputs) and the page load time will exceed 60 seconds causing it to time out.

I have looked at http://speedtest.comcast.net/ and http://www.host-tracker.com/ to check both my local internet speed and the website host.

I've checked both sites when the page is loading fine and when it is timing out. The results are always comparable. I would of expected to see a slow down either on my end or on the website when it is timing out but this is not happening.

What else could be causing this sort of massive slowdown that I am experiencing? I've already spent time optimizing the php code and while it does load quicker now it still times out.

Once the site starts timing out, this behavior seems to continue for between 10 to 60 minutes. After which it starts loading quickly again even though none of the code or data has been altered.

I am using an access database file to store and retrieve information. Below is a sample of the methods being used.

```
//Get Country Data
       $Countryconn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
       $Countryconn->open("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=".$CurrentDirectory."\MQesDatabase.mdb");
       $CountryData =  $Countryconn->execute("SELECT Account4Rate, Base_Productivity_Factor, Account0Rate, Account1Rate, Account2Rate, Account8Rate FROM Country WHERE ID=$CountryIDValue");
//Get Crew Rates
$CivilRate=$CountryData->Fields(2);
       $CivilRateValue=$CivilRate->value;
       $CivilRateValue= $CivilRateValue*$MarkupFactor;
```

Then to Store information

```
$CurrentAreaTotals = $conn->execute("SELECT DManHours, SManHours, Labor, Subcontract, LMaterial, OMaterial, LProcurement, OProcurement, CEquipment, Total FROM Areas WHERE ID=$SelectedArea");

..

 $CumAreaLMaterial = $CurrentAreaTotals->Fields(4); $CumAreaLMaterialValue = $CumAreaLMaterial->value;
                $CumAreaLMaterialValue = $CumAreaLMaterialValue+($MaterialCostValue/$CurrentRRateValue)*$CQuantityValue;
                if ($CivilSubContractDataValue == 0){ $rs = $conn->execute("UPDATE Areas SET LMaterial = $CumAreaLMaterialValue WHERE ID=$AreaCodeValue");}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to see what's hogging your resources if you give us no code we could inspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a database response issue. If the database is stored on a machine with maxed resources, it could be taking a long time to respond to the request.

EDIT:

To test the database response time, you can use this function and get an idea:

```
<?php
   function logToFile($filename, $msg)
   { 
       // open file
       $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
       // append date/time to message
       $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg; 
       // write string
       fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
       // close file
       fclose($fd);
   }
?>
```

Then call that function right before your `$conn->execute()` statements and then again right after. For example:

```
logToFile("testlog.txt", "Beginning")
$CountryData =  $Countryconn->execute("SELECT Account4Rate, Base_Productivity_Factor, Account0Rate, Account1Rate, Account2Rate, Account8Rate FROM Country WHERE ID=$CountryIDValue");
logToFile("testlog.txt", "Finished")
```

Writing to a file will increase your overall times a bit but it will give you an idea for how long your queries are taking to run.

Comment: The database is being stored on the host site, along with the rest of the website. I've tried checking website response time and it seems to be the same regardless how slowly the code is executing. Is there a way I can monitor the database response time?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: looking into it, I don't believe I have any in place. The Database files are manipulated (even created in some cases) purely by the php files. When I need to check the data and structure independently I download the files and open them up in ms access. but I don't otherwise use any dbms.

Comment: You can get an idea by writing the current time to a file before and after doing database calls. I edited my answer to add some code.

Comment: Thanks! The code works and is easy to implement. It should give me an idea if it's the whole thing that is slowing down or if just certain parts are.

Comment: I'm marking your response as the answer since I was able to use the code you provided to determine what was causing the load time issues.

I had a section of code that was accessing the database file on each pass though of a loop. When the database access time would lag this had a dramatic effect on how quickly each pass though on the loop would process. I was able to rework the code so that it could pull the needed information outside of the loop making this access time have a minimal effect on the report (only adds 1 to 2 seconds instead of 30+). 

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a database response issue as Sam said. This sounds like a good use case for some general logging, tracking how long the database queries and the page as a whole takes to load would be a good start in narrowing it down to a particular piece of code or a db query.

If you're interested in more detailed suggestions I'd like to know what kind of database you're using and if you're using a framework for your PHP code.

Comment: I have an access database file that I am using to store information. I have updated the question to include the type of statements I am using to store and retrieve the information.